# MockedProvider is not providing response once using custom apollo client

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo

We want to test the below code, where we have our custom apollo client and this custom apollo client uses WebSocket link. When we run the test file given below, onCompleted callback in the query does not get called.

```
 const { loading, error, data, refetch } = useQuery(
    GET_DOG_QUERY,
    {
      variables: { nameOne },
      client: apolloClient,
      fetchPolicy: "network-only",
      onCompleted: data => {
        console.log("Abhinav123456789");
      }
    }
  );
```

Below is the mocked request and response:

```
    const mocks = [
    {
      request: {
        query: GET_DOG_QUERY,
        variables: {
          nameOne: 'Buck',
        },
      },
      result: () => {
        return {
          data: {
            dog: { id: '1', name: 'Buck', breed: 'bulldog' },
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ];
```

Below is the test case we are trying to verify

```
 test("find loader", async () => {
    await act(async () => {
      wrapper = mount(
        <MockedProvider mocks={mocks} addTypename={false}>
          <DeviceTenantMapTable {...defaultProps} />
        </MockedProvider>
      );
    });
    await act(async () => {
      await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 0));
    });
    wrapper.upadate();
    expect(wrapper.find('[data-test="table customer-data-table"]').prop("isLoading")).toBe(true);
  });
```

Please tell us how to proceed with the test with our custom Apollo client component.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced a similar issue where we had two Apollo clients in our codebase. One was passed to the wrapping `ApolloProvider` element, whereas the other is an exported constant that gets used in `UseQuery` hooks, just like in the above example.

In the case of an Apollo client passed into a hook, the `MockedProvider` does not do anything. Instead you have to mock your client that you pass to `UseQuery` as a param.
This is how I mocked it in my tests:

```js
jest.mock('../ModuleOfYourClient', () => {
  const { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache } = require('@apollo/client');
  const { MockLink } = require('@apollo/client/testing');

  const mocks = require('./YourMockedData');

  const mockedApolloClient = new ApolloClient({
    cache: new InMemoryCache({ addTypename: false }),
    link: new MockLink(mocks.mockedData, false),
  });

  return {
    ...jest.requireActual('../ModuleOfYourClient'),
    apolloClient: mockedApolloClient,
  };
});
```